# GAE, Python 2.5, Python 2.6 Side-by-side on windows

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

On my development system, I have Python 2.6, Django 1.1 and GAE.

- I have three projects running on Python 2.6 and Django 1.1.
- I have 1 project using GAE, Python 2.6 and Django 1.1.

I have heard that my set-up for running GAE using Python 2.6 may create some head-scratching problems while deploying it on the production server, because GAE supports only Python 2.5, and using 2.6 is not recommended.

Can I develop GAE application using Python 2.6? If not, what should I do? I am using Windows Vista as my development system.

**Please note :** I don't want to disturb my other projects in development, which uses Python 2.6 and Django 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.openplans.org/) to isolate your development environments, so you can have one running 2.5 and the others running 2.6.

Edited to add: once 2.5 is installed, you can initialize your virtualenv to use it with the -p option:

```
virtualenv -p /path/to/python2.5/python.exe destination_dir
```

Comment: I have installed python 2.5 and 2.6 on my windows system. How do I create virutualenv that uses 2.5. I searched the google but didnt find answer... Can you help me out?

Comment: I have run this command in directory d:\testenv\ [virtualenv -p "c:\Python25\python.exe" .] But it give error: [c:\Python25\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using python 2.6 specific syntax/code your application is safe to run on GAE.

Answer (score 0):

Re virtualenv question above: virtualenv have a parameter
`--python=PYTHON_EXE` that you can point to the interpreter you'd like
it to use. Running `virtualenv` without parameters or with an `--help`
option whill show you which options you may pass it.